# Auto-Adjusting column width in HTML table

Tags: php, html, css, html-table, css-tables

I am creating a table containing the URL history of a user. The data is collected from an SQL database using PHP, the table is produced depending on the data which the user selects using the check boxes in the image below.

I want the table to use the full width of the page, as it is doing at the moment. However I want the column width to be automatically adjusted. As you can see in the image, various columns are a lot wider than they need to be.

I have attached the CSS code which I am using below.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
    table#DisplayData {
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    word-wrap:break-word
    }

    table#DisplayData th, td {
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    word-wrap:break-word
    margin: auto;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: What do you want each column's width to be dependent upon? You might need a JS solution for this, or percentage width columns.

Comment: Ideally the length of the header for some columns. However, for rows such as Url, i'd like them to be as long as possible but still stay on the page horizontally?

Comment: I'd recommend hard-coded percentage width columns. You'd use into `<colgroup>`, `<col>`, `table-layout: fixed`, and `width: X%` on the `col`s.

Answer (score 3):

Change your `table-layout` to `auto` (or don't include it, as `auto` is the default).

A demo [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout):

[image]

Comment: If I use 'auto' or take that line out completely, my table then runs off the side of the page.

Comment: If you've already tried that, could you provide a verfiable example in your question? It's hard for me to answer fully otherwise.